# Mixpanel JQL - Group by Properties

Tags: mixpanel, jql

I'm new to Mixpanel and I'm trying to use the JQL endpoint of the API to retrieve a daily feed of users who have been placed into experiments. My JQL is as follows:

```
function main() {     
      return Events({       
            from_date: "2022-04-01",       
            to_date: "2022-04-01",     
            })     
      .filter(function(event) { 
            return event.name == "$experiment_started" 
            }
      )
      .groupBy(["properties.experiment_name"], mixpanel.reducer.count());   
}
```

This returns an empty array despite there being events for the date in question, and it returns figures when I remove the group by, so I know the problem must be on the property name I'm using. The trouble is, I have literally tried almost every different way to write "Experiment Name" that I can think of to no avail - prefixing with $, upper case, lower case, using an underscore, you name it but to no avail. The exact name in the UI is "Experiment name".

Can someone confirm which special way of writing "Experiment Name" will work, and how I can figure this out for myself in the UI so I don't have to break the hourly rate limit through trial and error?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure reading your post, did you try
```
"properties.Experiment Name"
```
?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Support Engineer at a Mixpanel and taking a look at your JQL it seems there is just a syntax error. The event is recorded in Mixpanel as '$experiment_started' which you are filtering on correctly but you are grouping on 'experiment_name' but instead you should be grouping on 'Experiment name'.